# Detect when a particular element in an iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there a way for me to detect when a particular element within an `iframe` is loaded without waiting for the full iframe content to load?

The problem I have is that the iframe is filled with many SVG buttons that take a long time to load and process and hooking into the load event of the iframe forces the action I want to take to wait for them to load fully. I want to access one element out of the iframe and wanted to know if it was possible to detect that that element has been loaded without waiting for the full contents of the iframe to load.

JavaScript or jQuery solutions are both file with me.

Comment: You could check every x milliseconds whether or not it exists, however depending on the number of elements in the iframe, that can become taxing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('iframe').onload = function() {
     alert("loaded")
})
```

This will fire when the HTML is loaded, but before it has been fully parsed and rendered.

Beyond that you'd have to poll to see of the element you're looking for is in the page.

Comment: How do you detect when the iframe is fully parsed and rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it :

```
$("iframe").contents().find("your iframe elem").load(function(){
    alert('element loaded.');
});
```

Comment: This will only work if the "your iframe elem" has been parsed and can load content (such as an img or another iframe).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The element is never found and the alert doesn't fire. I'm not sure if it makes a difference that I'm inserting the iframe dynamically.