# I have two iframe on same page but it load in different time duration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have two or more iframe on the same page. I have to load all iframe at once and appear in same time. Currently it loaded one by one. I want to load all at once and asynchronous with page loading.

Comment: basically iframe is not generating by JS. Its comming from cookie which has complete iframe body

Comment: I have done this creating multiple iframe through javascript by which each element are created asynchronous. Thus the loading time is really fast.

Answer (score 1):

### My solution:

- First add hidden css to all iframe's.
- Then use onload method on each iframe. This method will add some
  classes for example `loaded` and check on finish is all iframe has
  this class.
- If don't have - do nothing, otherwise show all iframes.

Here you can find example of usage onload method: [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_onload)

Comment: To see how to detect if a iframe is loaded see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265567/detect-when-a-particular-element-in-an-iframe-is-loaded)

Comment: what if multiple iframe is added?

Comment: iframe is not populating when I add display:none property of CSS

Comment: tabs_window = tabs.split('<div'); 
    $.each(tabs_window, function(i, val){
    $('#tabs').append('<div style="visibility: hidden;" '+val);
   });` 
the val variable contain the iframe source.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance?%3E) will greatly help you. It's a nice detailed explanation of the iframe techniques and performance issues and might just what you are looking for. As mentioned in the above answer and in this link here, the onLoad function call is what you are going to need.