# How to load multiple iframes concurrently?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, iframe

I want to load 10-15 iframes simultaneously in such way that it can render whenever data received from URL.

I have tried to use async function but it still working like one after one loading of iframes

Here is code:

```
<iframe src="" height="50" width="320" id="frame_1"></iframe>
<iframe src="" height="50" width="320" id="frame_2"></iframe>
<iframe src="" height="50" width="320" id="frame_3"></iframe>
<iframe src="" height="50" width="320" id="frame_4"></iframe>
<iframe src="" height="50" width="320" id="frame_5"></iframe>

<script>
async function loadIframe1() {
 console.log(1)
 document.getElementById('frame_1').src='file1.html';


}
async function loadIframe2() {
 console.log(2)
 document.getElementById('frame_2').src='file1.html';

 }
async function loadIframe3() {
 console.log(3)
 document.getElementById('frame_3').src='file1.html';

}
async function loadIframe4() {
 console.log(4)
 document.getElementById('frame_4').src='file1.html
}
async function loadIframe5() {
 console.log(5)
 document.getElementById('frame_5').src='file1.html';

}

loadIframe1();
loadIframe2();
loadIframe3();
loadIframe4();
loadIframe5();
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is needlessly duplicative currently and could be optimised by having a single function that loads all iframes. Secondly, prefixing your functions with `async` doesn't do what you think it does; it has no bearing on how iframe content is loaded. Thirdly, iframe couldn't *shouldn't* block normal execution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114239/is-there-a-way-to-load-an-iframe-asynchronously

Comment: I have checked that answer already
What i want is to display all available iframes at time not one after another

Comment: Why don't you create iFrames from JS instead of adding iframe element in HTML?

Comment: Even if i simply write iframe html code buy putting same url in src attribute 
all iframes are not loading at time

Comment: Check this link and let me know of it solves your issue: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance?%3E

Comment: It is found on this page, might might make it a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805427/i-have-two-iframe-on-same-page-but-it-load-in-different-time-duration

Comment: My purpose of loading iframes are not for showing something on those iframes but I just want to load a pixel url for tracking purpose of ads

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to display all iframes at once.

You could use CSS with `display: none` and whenever they are all loaded, set them back to `display: block`.

This is one way how to do it:

```js
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
const allIframes = iframes.length;
let iframeCounter = 0;

for (let iframe of iframes) {
  iframe.onload = () => {
    iframeCounter++;
    if (allIframes === iframeCounter) {
      let css = window.document.styleSheets[0];
      css.insertRule(`
        iframe {
          display: block;
        }
      `, css.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```